# Unknown path in my environment variables

Tags: windows-8, environment-variables, path, console2

I have a path in my Windows 8 Environment variables `.bin;`does this make any sense? Is it most likely a typo or typeover?

I was having some issues with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) working in my [Console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) and when I went to check my environment variables I saw this. Any ideas?

One thing to note is that it was the last environment variable in the path. Most likely put there by [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) or something after that installation. My end of the path looked like this:

`C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows;.bin;`

Comment: Search your disk for a directory name `.bin`. It could be a trojan.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00x\Control\Session Manager\Environment` in `regedit`
2. Find a registry branch that preserved the environment variables.
3. Export `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00x\Control\Session Manager\Environment` to regfile.
4. Edit reg file and change `ControlSet00x` to `CurrentControlSet`
5. Megre registry file.
6. Reboot

[image: Regedit Environment variable]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't just go editing registry keys and executing any command someone on the internet tells me to, even if they have a ton of points on SuperUser. lol I'm not trying to be rude and I really do appreciate your answer, but is there any possibility you could let me know just what it is I would be doing here? And how does this pertain to my problem? 

Again, I really do appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, just looking for some clarification on what it is I'm doing..

Comment: Oh and what is your avatar? I like it.. Nevermind, "White Tree of Gondor" lol, I still like it!

Comment: @EricB Try to add pictures, then the idea will become easier. And yes you can manually fill the environment variables in the system properties, is safer, but a chore. You watch the movie with subtitles about World War II in the description.